# Is there a message for functions evaluating to infinity?

Tags: warning-messages

Everyone has perhaps been irritated by the `Power::infty` message:

```
Cos[0]/Sin[0]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

```
(*  ComplexInfinity  *)
```

But I want such a message in case like this:

```
Cos[x]/Sin[x] /. x -> 0
(*  ComplexInfinity  *)
```

There is no message because `Cos[x]/Sin[x]` evaluates to `Cot[x]`, and `Cot[0]` evaluates to `ComplexInfinity` without a warning.  Similarly `Log[0]` evaluates to `-Infinity` without warning.

*Is there a system option or message that can be turned on so that expressions like `Cot[0]` and `Log[0]` give a warning?*

Notes:

- These functions may be embedded in larger expressions.
- It is possible that the infinity will eventually generate an error as it propagates through a computation.  But it's also possible that a finite number will be divided by infinity and evaluate to `0`, like `1/ComplexInfinity`, in which case it might be a disaster:

  ```
  1 + 1/(1 + Log[0])
  (*  1  *)
  ```

Comment: `Limit[Cos[x]/Sin[x], x -> 0]` or `FullSimplify[Cos[x]/Sin[x]] /. x -> 0`?  No errors.

Comment: On the flip side, when I had an application dealing with ratios of gamma functions, it was convenient that the reciprocal of a gamma function evaluated at a nonpositive integer evaluated to 0…

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I meant it only *might* be a disaster.

Comment: For example, docs for `Log[ ]` states _Zero and infinite arguments give symbolic results:_ So if you want error messages you'll need to redefine to your own functions

Comment: Not aware of a built-in setting (which might well exist), but you can hack it with something like this: `Unprotect[DirectedInfinity];
DirectedInfinity::infy = "Infinite expression encountered";
DirectedInfinity /: call : _[___, _DirectedInfinity, ___] /; ! TrueQ[inInf] :=
Block[{inInf = True},Message[DirectedInfinity::infy];call]; Protect[DirectedInfinity]`. Can wrap that in a dynamic environment using ``Internal`InheritedBlock``, to avoid global redefinitions. This surely isn't remotely as nice as would be a built-in mechanism, but it may work.

Comment: I'm not at a computer now, but maybe you can use `TraceScan[]` to find instances of `DirectedInfinity[]` during evaluation, and throw an appropriate message if it finds one?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, that seems to work, except for a top-level `Cot[0]`. If I change the declaration to `call : _DirectedInfinity /; ! TrueQ[inInf] :=...`, it catches a top-level infinity.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I expect that would work, but wouldn't it slow things down?

Comment: I don't know and can't do the experiment myself, which is why I was suggesting it. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually, your version is even much better, since it produces a `DownValue` on `DirectedInfinity`, which is much better / safer than `UpValue` of such a general form as I suggested.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius `1/0` gives a symbolic result, too, doesn't it?  I'm not sure a symbolic result means there's no built-in message, off by default, that could be turned on.  The more convincing evidence is that no one who has commented, including you and me, seems to know of one.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Maybe it wasn't clear: I **want** to get an error.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin No one has come up with a better idea. I realize it is a bit of a hack, but would you consider posting an answer?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Redefinition of `DirectedInfinity`

One way would be to add a DownValue to `DirectedInfinity` (the final form suggested by [MicahelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)):

```
Unprotect[DirectedInfinity];
Clear[DirectedInfinity];
DirectedInfinity::infy = "Infinite Expression encountered";
DirectedInfinity /: call_DirectedInfinity /; ! TrueQ[inInf] :=  
  Block[{inInf = True},
    Update[DirectedInfinity];
    Message[DirectedInfinity::infy];
    call
  ];
Protect[DirectedInfinity];
```

So that, for example

```
1 + 1/(1 + Log[0])
```

> During evaluation of In[67]:= DirectedInfinity::infy: Infinite Expression encountered >>
>
> During evaluation of In[67]:= DirectedInfinity::infy: Infinite Expression encountered >>
>
> 1

The call to `Update` is necessary to prevent an internal optimization, that would otherwise result in the messages being suppressed on subsequent calls of `DirectedInfinity`.

#### A safer version using local environment

Note that this isn't a safe modification, since it globally modifies a built-in function. As such, it may have unanticipated consequences. A safer way to do this would be to use `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``, and a dynamic environment to wrap around a piece of code you want to evaluate in this mode.

First, we have to remove the changes we made:

```
Unprotect[DirectedInfinity];
Clear[DirectedInfinity];
Protect[DirectedInfinity];
```

Here is a reasonably general generator of such dynamic environments:

```
ClearAll[withRedefined];
SetAttributes[withRedefined, HoldRest];
withRedefined[f_Symbol,beforeCall_,afterCall_, extraCode_]:=
  Function[code,
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{f},
      Module[{inF, dv=DownValues[f]},
        With[{protected = Unprotect[f]},
          DownValues[f]={};
          extraCode;    
          (call:f[args___])/;!TrueQ[inF]:=
            Block[{inF=True},
              beforeCall[args];
              With[{res = call},
                afterCall[args, res];
                res
              ]
            ];
            DownValues[f]=Join[DownValues[f],dv];
            Protect[protected];
        ];
        code
      ]
    ],
    HoldAll
  ];
```

With this function, we can create our custom dynamic environment easily:

```
withMessageOnInfinity = 
  withRedefined[
    DirectedInfinity
    ,
    Function[
      Update[DirectedInfinity];
      Message[DirectedInfinity::infy]
    ]
    ,
    Function[Null]
    ,
    DirectedInfinity::infy = "Infinite Expression encountered";
  ];
```

So now we have without dynamic environment just the usual behavior:

```
1 + 1/(1 + Log[0])

(* 1 *)
```

while using the environment we get:

```
withMessageOnInfinity[1 + 1/(1 + Log[0])]
```

> During evaluation of In[21]:= DirectedInfinity::infy: Infinite Expression encountered >>
>
> 1

Comment: Thank you. I always learn something from your code generation examples.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Glad to help, as always. Thanks for the accept.